# Split text across DIN A4 pages

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6, media-queries

I'm working on creating an editor using DIN A4 pages with specific text formatting using React.

Right now, my content is handled by an editable div (with more divs nested inside it for formatting).

If possible, I would like to be able to retrieve all content (including user-done page breaks) as one long HTML string. I was considering to split pages in the state, but maybe it is better to somehow render automatically.

So, in short: I need my text to automatically split into pages, but be editable as one long string.

What would be the best approach to doing this?

For an example, look at https://youmescript.com/.

Comment: You can use an array of strings or array of objects intead of one long string. Array consist of infomation by pages. In order to format you need to find a format for page information to store the content.

Comment: I read that as you want to develop an editor for A4 printing.  But printing is a mess, each browser do their own margin and scaling in their own way.  if you manage your own paper margin and export to pdf (where you 100% control the font, size, spacing etc.), it should be doable with js.

Comment: @XPD I tried that approach, results in horrible performance or is simply unusable for dynamic content.

Comment: @Sheepy That's not my problem. I don't need printing yet. I need displaying. Even then, I know how to solve printing. I just need a WYSIWYG editor displaying A4 pages.

Comment: To clarify, my main problem with my tried approach is that overflow detection is unreliable, inefficient or simply not working as intended.

Comment: Why do you think there is a performance issue?. The format you choose decide how dynamic the content will be allowed. And also the efficiency and the accuracy rendering from and back format.

Comment: @TemporaryName I think you are working on a scriptwriting editor? I am also working on a similar project (script writing in WYSIWYG editor with pagination support). I am trying to get the paging feature in the prosemirror editor.

Comment: @XPD Because I need to loop through the content to check for overflowing, this ends up crashing my React component in most cases if the children are React components. Only way to make it work is non-React and that is more difficult to integrate again.

Comment: @AmanGupta Exactly. Have you had success?

Comment: No. Almost all the open-source WYSIWYG editor does not support pagination. I am currently working on listing down the required features for the script writing. may be from next week I will start working on a custom editor. Will keep you posted. You do the same if you find any luck.